# Mysql como sacar los días de descanso entre 2 registros 1 tabla

Tags: mysql

Hola quisiera poder sacar la diferencia entre dos registros en mysql .

Ejemplo

1 registro tengo id | numHabita | Fecha ingreso |  Fecha Egreso

2 registro tengo  id | numHabita | Fecha ingreso |  Fecha Egreso

necesito como sacar la diferencia que hay desde que salio hasta que entro el próximo cliente(es decir los días q estuvo libre la habitación) en mysq claro .

```
SELECT * FROM habita WHERE numHabita = 5
```

Esto me saca todos los registros de la habitación numero 5 lo que  me gustaría sacar la cantidad de días que esta libre la habitación  tengo un id y numero de habitación.Desde ya gracias.

Comment: Que has intentado? Tienes algún error?. Recuerda que debes [elaborar preguntas en las que incluyas tu código](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) para que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad. En caso contrario pueden terminar cerradas. Pásate por [esta sección](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que comprendas mejor de lo que te estoy hablando.

Comment: En que quieres la diferencia en dias???

Comment: Debes tener algo en comun los dos registros para que puedas armar tu consulta por ejemplo el # de habitación, mira ver si puedes poner algo mas de información como te recomendaba @DjCrazy

Comment: Prueba con la función `datediff()`.